# Countability of rationals in an open interval

Tags: elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

Let us assume that every non empty open interval $(a,b)$ contains a rational.
Then how can we prove that $(a,b)$ contains infinitely many and hence countably many rationals? It is not stated whether a and b are rational or irrational.

Comment: To show there are countably many rationals in an interval, you may need to know there are countably many rationals in total and an infinite subset of these is also countable

Comment: Yes but how can I prove that without using that theorem

Comment: You know the permitted assumptions.  Assuming that every non-empty open interval $(a,b)$ contains an irrational allows you to prove that a particular $(a,b)$ contains infinitely many irrationals.  But it will not contain only countably many irrationals

Comment: You should say clearly what you want to use and what you want to avoid using. Until then, voting to close.

Comment: I want to prove this without using the theorem that infinite subset of countable set is countable.

Comment: Can you prove there is a collection of infinitely many and pairwise disjoint open subintervals of $(a,b)?$ For example, the open interval from $a$ to the midpoint of $(a,b),$ the open interval from the midpoint of $(a,b)$ to the midpoint of the just described open interval, etc. Or, if you want to get really exotic, use the complementary intervals of a Cantor set that is a subset of $(a,b).$

Answer (score 4):

To show that there is infinitely many rationals in the interval:

> Suppose that there are only $n$ rationals in the interval, say
>   $$a<r_1<r_2<\ldots<r_n<b$$ But there is a rational in the interval
>   $(a,r_1)$. Contradiction.

To show that there are countably many, look at this way to count all the rationals:

[image]

In this path, there will be some numbers in $(a,b)$. Select only these ones and you are done.

Comment: This proves that there are infinitely many rationals, what about countability?

Comment: I got your point. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

A "constructive" way.

By your assumption, we have a rational number $p\in \left(a,\frac{a+b}{2}\right)$ and a rational number $q\in \left(\frac{a+b}{2},b\right)$ (note that $p<q$).
Now, for any positive integer $n$,
$$p_n:=p+\frac{q-p}{2^n}\in \mathbb{Q}\cap (p,q)\subset \mathbb{Q}\cap (a,b).$$
Since they are all distinct (because $p_{n+1}<p_n$), then $\{p_n\}_{n\geq 0}$ is a countable set of rational numbers inside $(a,b)$.

Comment: I am curious to know that how did you get that formula of pn?

Comment: @Priyanka The transformation $x\to p+(q-p)x$, send the interval $[0,1]$ into $[p,q]$. Moreover it maps rationals in rationals. So it suffices to find a sequence of rationals in $[0,1]$.