# Are there any proof that show something about this language?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, formal-languages

Suppose we show any positive rational number with alphabet a string $S$ on $\{0,1,\#\}$
that $S=x_kx_{k-1}\dots x_1\#y_ky_{k-1}\dots y_1$ such that $x_i,y_i\in\{0,1\}$
show an rational number. How it's possible to show all rational numbers in interval $[\sqrt{2},\sqrt{7}]$ with context sensitive grammars?

[According to this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1893967/countability-of-rationals-in-an-open-interval), I know rational numbers between an interval are countable, but how we can conclude that, we can show all rational numbers in interval $[\sqrt{2},\sqrt{7}]$ by a context senstive langyage?

Comment: I upvote the problem, but it surely will be closed soon as you showed no effort. If you want to avoid closing up  then do that.

Comment: I fail to understand what the core of the problem is here. The structure x#y can be checked easily. You can also do the division in linearly bounded space, though not the entire result might fit in there. What might be tha hardest thing might be the comparison against the two bounds, because these do not have finite representations. Comparing against an approximation might lead to errors at the very margin. At any rate, please elaborate a bit more on where exactly you see the problem, and which part you know how to do.